# Can't pass value in image tag

Tags: php, jquery

hi i am new in php i am tryig to pass value on image click through ajax call but i can not find value on click on that image

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
        function getItem()
        {
            var dataString = "category_id=" +$(".category_id").val();
            alert(dataString);
            alert(category_id);
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "header.php",
              data: dataString,
              success:function(data)
              {
                $("#partyId").html(data); 
              }
          });
        }
  </script>
</head>
```

my html code is like this here i am trying get that category id on click of that image but i can not get this id on click on image

```
<?php
$catarray = array();
$selectcat = "SELECT * FROM category";
$selectcatRes = mysql_query($selectcat);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectcatRes))
{
$category_id = $row['category_id'];
$category_nm = $row['category_nm'];
$cat_img = $row['cat_img'];
echo'<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 category_id">
<a href="images/product_1.jpg" class="fh5co-figure to-animate image-popup category_id"  onclick="getItem();">
<figure>
<img width="500" height="300" src="vraj/_cat_img/thumb/'.$row['cat_img'].'" onclick="getItem();" class="img-responsive category_id">
</figure>
<h3 class="fh5co-figure-lead">'.$category_nm.'</h3>
<p class="fh5co-figure-text"></p>
</a>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you see in console?

Comment: ReferenceError: category_id is not defined @techLove

Comment: You're trying to get the value of an image. Where's the `value` attribute in the image?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't output the category id anywhere and so it's impossible to retrieve it.

Output it to a data attribute on the div, remove the other `category_id` classes and then change the click event to delegated like below (removing getItem). Using this you can get the category id when the anchor or image is clicked.

I also changed to pass an object as the ajax data because there is no need to concatenate your own data string.

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efhv2m1u/)**

Updated PHP:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectcatRes))
{
$category_id = $row['category_id'];
$category_nm = $row['category_nm'];
$cat_img = $row['cat_img'];
echo'<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12 category_id" data-category_id="' . htmlspecialchars($category_id) . '">
<a href="images/product_1.jpg" class="fh5co-figure to-animate image-popup">
<figure>
<img width="500" height="300" src="vraj/_cat_img/thumb/'.$row['cat_img'].'"  class="img-responsive">
</figure>
<h3 class="fh5co-figure-lead">'.$category_nm.'</h3>
<p class="fh5co-figure-text"></p>
</a>
</div>';
}
```

Updated JavaScript:

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.category_id a.image-popup, .category_id img.img-responsive', function(){
        var category_id = $(this).closest('.category_id').data('category_id');
        alert(category_id);
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "header.php",
            data: { category_id : category_id },
            success:function(data)
            {
                $("#partyId").html(data); 
            }
          });
          return false;
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I made a small change to the JavaScript. Try the updated code.

Comment: 1) TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined 2)TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined it's show me error on console

Comment: Check your code matches the answer because we can see this working in the jsFiddle I added. Also added `return false;` but that isn't to fix any error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that don't work.

1. Your img tag has no `value` attribute
2. You never defined a variable called `category_id`
3. You have multiple elements with a class called `category_id`, you should use an `id` to have a unique selector.
4. I guess by `value` you mean the `src` attribute? This would be `.attr('src')` and not `val()`. `val()` is only used for input fields because they actually have a value attribute to store data.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the edit, I didn't realize the mistake ;-).

Comment: right now on alert categoryid i am getting output like this http://localhost/vraj/images/product_1.jpg..